# Callback protocol for functions with different kwargs

Tags: python, python-3.x, callback, type-hinting, python-typing

I have a function that takes a `callback` function as a parameter:

```
def function(arg1: int, callback):
    ...
```

I am trying to add a type hint for the `callback` function. Now, the callback functions that are passed to this function have the same positional args but the kwargs can be completely different (both in type and name).

```
def function1(arg1: int, arg2: str, **kwargs1):
    ...

def function2(arg1: int, arg2: str, **kwargs2):
    ...
```

I am trying to write a [Callback Protocol](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html#callback-protocols) that fits these 2 functions, but so far I don't see a way to make this work when the kwargs are different. Is there a way to create a unified Callback protocol in this case?

Answer (score 6):

You can create this Callback protocol:

```
from typing_extensions import Protocol


class Callback(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, arg1: int, arg2: str, **kwargs): ...
```

and type hint `callback` as `Callback`:

```
def function(arg1: int, callback: Callback): ...
```

Now, among these three function calls:

```
def function1(arg1: int, arg2: str, **kwargs1): ...
def function2(arg1: int, arg2: str, **kwargs2): ...
def function3(arg1: int): ...

function(0, function1) # Success.
function(0, function2) # Success.
function(0, function3) # Error.
```

`mypy` will report success for the first two, but report an error for the third one because of the missing `arg2`.

The key thing to realize here is that the name of the keyword-arguments parameter does not actually matter. If I take `function2` and rename `arg1` to `arg_1`, `mypy` would complain about that. This is because the public interface of `function2` has changed in a backwards-incompatible way. For example, I would have to modify `arg1=0` at any call site to `arg_1=0`.

But if I take the same function and rename `kwargs2` to `kwargs_2`, the public interface does not actually change! This is because it was impossible to ever explicitly refer to the `kwargs` / `kwargs1` / `kwargs2` parameter at a call site in the first place. Take this example:

```
function2(arg1=0, arg2="", kwargs2={})
```

If I were to dump `kwargs2` from inside the function, it would actually have the key `"kwargs2"` mapped to `{}`, instead of being an empty dictionary itself. This shows that it is impossible to rely on the name of the keyword-arguments parameter. `mypy` can therefore allow different names when checking if the public interface of `function2` matches that of a `Callback`.

As for the type, `kwargs`, `kwargs1` and `kwargs2` all have a type of `Dict[str, Any]` left annotated. Since you're consistent across all 3, `mypy` reports success here, while also enabling you to take advantage of `Any` for keyword arguments specific to `function1` or `function2`.

Comment: How does Python associate the protocol declaration with function1, function 2?

Comment: @hasii See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system, and how mypy implements it via: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html. Python does not require an explicit association between the protocol declaration and function1 or function2.